# how to convert the expression $(x+y^2)^{1/6}$ to a polar equation?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

how do you convert the expression  $$(x+y^2)^{1/6}$$ to its polar form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a simple variable change, with $(r, \theta)$ being the new variables: $x \to r\cos(\theta)$ and $y \to r\sin(\theta)$. In your case, this becomes:
$$(r \cos(\theta) + r^2 \sin^2(\theta))^\frac16$$

Comment: Thanks! What if i wanted to integrate it? Would I take out the r, cos(theta), sin(theta) like this:

(r^4) * dr * d(theta)
(sin^2(theta)+cos(theta)) * d(theta)

Comment: d$r$ and d$\theta$ need to be handled with care, the coordinates are curvilinear. Maybe you should create another question with your complete integral.

Answer (score 0):

Hint : Use the polar coordinate transformation
$$x=r\cos\theta,\ \ \ \ y=r\sin\theta$$